# operation was rejected by your operating system error message when I try to install prompt sync with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried alot of solutions that worked for others but it won't work for me and it's really frustrating. This is the entire error message

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path E:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'E:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-21T13_59_04_266Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried giving cmd adminstrative permissions, I tried turning off virus threat protection, I tried doing this on the visual code terminal, I tried clearing cache, and tons of other stuff I can't remember.

Comment: The error says you're getting a permission error trying to create "E:". If there's already a drive E mounted, seems like that's the error I would expect.